# How to show DAG progress from Apache Airflow to a custom webapp

Tags: airflow

**Context**

I'm building a react webapp to help users start certain jobs on a VM. These jobs can be of different types (`download data` followed by `process data` as a job for example). Each of these jobs can take multiple hours to complete. Whenever user clicks a button, I'm sending a POST request to the Airflow Webserver REST API (sitting on my VM) to trigger a DAG run.

Since I have access to Airflow's UI, I can see the progress of the DAG run and also the progress of each task in the DAG run.

**Problem:**

I want to show the progress and ETA of the DAG run (which was triggered by a user) in the react webapp for the users to see. I'm not sure how to do it.

**Current Solution:**

For now, I'm using a workaround. I'm setting `Variables` as 'checkpoints" so that I can keep polling the Variables endpoint to show progress to the user.

code example:

`dag.py`

```py
from airflow import DAG
from datetime import timedelta
from datetime import datetime
from airflow.operators.python import PythonOperator
from airflow.models import Variable
import json



def task1_callable(**context):

    dag_run_id = context["dag_run"].run_id

    # Some code
    Variable.set(dag_run_id, json.dumps({"result": "first sub task completed"}))

   # Some code

    Variable.set(dag_run_id, json.dumps({"result": "second sub task completed"}))

   # Some code


    Variable.set(dag_run_id, json.dumps({"result": "task1 completed"}))
  
def task2_callable(**context):

    dag_run_id = context["dag_run"].run_id

    # Some code
    Variable.set(dag_run_id, json.dumps({"result": "first sub task completed"}))

   # Some code

    Variable.set(dag_run_id, json.dumps({"result": "second sub task completed"}))

   # Some code


    Variable.set(dag_run_id, json.dumps({"final":True, "result": "task2 completed and your job is also finished"}))



with DAG(
    dag_id="some_id",
    schedule_interval=None,
    default_args={
        "owner": "airflow",
        "retries": 1,
        "retry_delay": timedelta(minutes=5),
        "start_date": datetime(2021, 1, 1),
    },
    catchup=False,
) as f:

    task1 = PythonOperator(
        task_id="task1",
        python_callable = task1_callable,
        run_as_user= "user",
    )

    task2 = PythonOperator(
        task_id="task2",
        python_callable = task2_callable,
        run_as_user= "user",
    )

task1 >> task2
```

**Now on the react side**, I'm just polling the Variables endpoint (`/variables/{variable_key}`) every 10 seconds so that I can show the user custom messages to convey their job progress.

But the main problem with this approach is that this is hard to maintain, and is not scalable. So I'm looking for the ***right*** way to share DAG progress to my users.

Thanks for reading this so far. Please let me know if I can provide any more details to improve clarity.

Comment: I would split your tasks into smaller ones and then you can track progress of those smaller pieces. That's airflow way I would say. Also instead of variables you can consider using statsd metrics.

Comment: Thanks @TomaszUrbaszek I can break them down into smaller tasks. But how do I get show the progress to the user? Let's say I have 10 tasks within a DAG. Can I show 1/0 completed, 2/10 completed, 3/10 completed etc?

Comment: That should be doable, just use GET dags/{dag_id}/dagRuns/{dag_run_id}/taskInstances it should return list of task with their current states. From that you can say that 3/10 was executed.

Comment: @roronoa any progress here?

Comment: nope @Brandt We let the polling method stay and eventually the project was killed